# Add custom varible in order email template in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have added custom variable in order email template .The variable have the value in sales_order and sales_order_grid table .Once place the order the custom variable doesn't not have any data it shows empty,after that go to backend  check that same order and click send email button manually got a email it shows the data in custom variable ,

Anyone face this problem help me?

Answer (score 0):

***Might the custom variable value set at the checkout success page.***
***If you using offline payment like Cash on delivery or Bank Transfer or Purchase then order email is fire before go to order success page and On placed time***.

*That way you do not get custom variable at email during order place.*

The event might be `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`

Comment: my variable saved during order in sales_order and sales_order_grid table and i am using online payment how to set variable in success page please help me

Comment: So can u please explain what i do that for this issue shall i create a event to send order email